# Delphi XE4 TWebBrowser - programmatically install self signed certificate for IE

Tags: delphi, internet-explorer, ssl

Is there any way to programmatically install a self signed SSL certificate for IE?
When navigating with WEBBrowser to a https site with self signed certificate the following dialog appears:
  http://prntscr.com/30sgz9

If pressing View Certificate/Install Certificate, the cert is installed and the dialog never appears.

So:

1.Can this be achieved programmatically without IE dialog to popup? or

2.Can other methods be invoked for TWebBrowser to ignore the security certificate/or trust it?

Answer (score 3):

It would be a security risk to auto-install unverifiable certificates.  It requires user intervention to confirm.

Comment: I can see use cases for this. For example, an intranet service which has a self-signed certificate and a sideband mechanism (e.g. in our case via a database) to deploy this to clients.